# Example of a non square-integrable martingale?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, lp-spaces, martingales

Are there (simple) examples of martingales which aren't square integrable?

Comment: As it has been suggested in the answer, you just need to add iid r.v. with zero mean but not in $L_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
X_{n+1} = X_n + T_{n+1}
$$
where $T_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and
$$
\Pr(T_{n+1}\in A) = \int_A \frac{dt}{(2+t^2)^{3/2}}
$$
for every measurable set $A$. (Thus $T_{n+1}$ has a t-distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom.)